# Adding Modifier (Mirrored)

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to add the Mirror modifier to a cube. I'm in Object Mode, I click add Modifier. When I click apply, the modifier disappears.

In Edit mode I can't add the modifier at all.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: You don't need to hit apply. Apply bakes in the modifier. It is already working dynamically before you hit apply.

Comment: But the mirrored "cube" doesn't appear, even though the modifier is set to visible and everything else too

Comment: The Modifier will Mirror across the objects Origin. In your case it looks like you should UnCheck X and Check Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mirror in the X direction (along the X axis). From your screenshot, the center of your object is in the middle of the 'left' side, which means that the original and generated (mirrored) points overlap.
Selecting the Y axis as mirror axis probably does what you want.

If you already applied the mirror modifier, you might also want to 'remove doubles' to get rid of superfluous vertices (which can give strange effects with e.g. subdivision or bevel modifiers)